# Basic authentication on a page with Nginx

Tags: nginx, authentication

I want to apply this for only index.php page not a directory. Is it possible? How should be config file?

```
location /images {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /qqqq/.htpasswd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a location for index.php that doesn't apply to a folder. Something like this I guess (using your auth syntax as I've never needed to use auth)

```
location /index.php {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /qqqq/.htpasswd;
}

location /images {
  // Whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation I think this should give you exactly what you need. The config file should be stored outside the web root. Like in /etc/ngnix:

```
location /images/index.php {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

To populate the .htpasswd file, do this:

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd my_username
```